# pywinaudio doesn't recognize all of the controls in Audacity

Tags: python, pywinauto, audacity

Hello I'm once again looking for help. While trying to automate Audacity I came to a problem with what I could find being that it doesn't recognize the sub menu Audacity uses. Whenever I run this code:

```
app = Application(backend= 'uia').start(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Audacity\audacity.exe')
app.Audacity.menu_select('File->Import')
app.Audacity.menu_select('Import->Audio... Ctrl+Shift+I')
```

It can't select the audio part (The whole submenu of Import is this way) but tries to find the nearest name to that, which apparently is somewhere in the transport menu. Also when I try to run `print_control_identifiers()` it doesn't show the submenu or any submenu in fact, even when trying to control the depth, it doesn't find the submenu.

Answer (score 2):

you can use 'inspect.exe' to identify the control on your application,  you can try UIA or MSAA to see which automation tech is feasible for the application.

or you can use other tools AccessBridgeExplorer or clicknium recorder to check whether the control can be recognized.